# Correct way to create an array with N number of elements without the old 'new Array(N)'?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Whenever I work with arrays, I always use the `[]` style, however, when I want to create an array with a fixed amount of elements I use `new Array(N)` (I don't know any other way of doing this)

I thought it wasn't big deal, until I read these strong words about this:

> Anyone doing this, using “new Array()” instead of “[]“, or “new
>   Object()” instead of “{}” needs to relearn JavaScript.

I really want to avoid writting bad code. Anyone mind tell me the right direction to go?

Comment: I actually think you're fine already.  You're using the `[]` syntax when you allocate an array most of the time, and `new Array(n)` when you want a specific size. Nothing wrong there, the quote you posted doesn't account for all situations.

Comment: @Michael good to know!, I guess I can now sleep with the lights off :)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using the `Array` constructor in this manner. It exists for a good reason.

Comment: @mithril333221 I'll check back in case someone enlightens me, but I don't know of another way to pre-allocate array size either short of `[null,null,null,null,...]`

Comment: See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch09_01.htm

Comment: And where did you find those "strong words"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit on the comments of http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: @mithril333221: I guess that's what happens when you treat comments on some blog as authoritative. Try a peer-reviewed book instead. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about some random comment on a blog in 2006. Especially since your use case isn't just `new Array()`. You're using the special-case constructor that is provided specifically for this purpose.

Besides, using `new Array()` instead of `[]` is hardly the worst thing someone can do with JS.

Comment: you probably are right, I should stop sleeping in fetal position and with the lights on because of a 6 year old post

Comment: Note that this doesn't make that quote necessarily _wrong_ -- just that we need to be able recognize hyperbole when we see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function repeat(str, len){
    str= str || '';
    len= len || 1;
    return Array(len+1).join(str);
}

repeat('*',25)

// returned value: (String)
```

Comment: This is a bad habit.  In generally, omitting the `new` keyword is dangerous and incorrect.  It just happens that the `Array` constructor behaves nicely and corrects your mistake by effectively re-calling the constructor with the `new` keyword internally.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a bad habit. Getting tripped up over new vs class factories a few times might happen to someone when they are getting used to javascript, but it hardly demands a dogmatic practice (always use new! or always use factories!) because you might once in a while assume a function is a factory when it isn't. That's easy to surface and correct. Go by what syntax offers the most syntactical clarity in actual use. `Point(x,y)` and JQuery's `$` make sense as factories, and `new` maybe for anything created infrequently and persistently, like `new Sprite(monsters["dragon"])`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, but here's how I would code it as an alternative to new Array(size), using JavaScript's literal syntax.

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = size;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` to create an array with n elements.

> Ex. Create array of zeros with length 7.

```
let arr = Array.from({length: 7}, () => 0);
```

!! `Array.from` is not supported by IE so use with caution.